# is apple signin mandatory in ios13?

Tags: react-native, ios13

I'm preparing for releasing new app with social sign in with react native.

From what I heard, new ios 13 app should have apple sign in if there is other social sign in.

However I have also normal sign in, which is my custom register and sign in function.

In this situation, do I need to implement apple sign in in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research? Somehow I really doubt that Apple has not made this information available anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you support third-party logins you must also support Sign-in with Apple. If you only have your own proprietary login you don't have to support Sign-in with Apple.

source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple